# Combinatorics - how many ways to divide balls in two groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, balls-in-bins

Suppose I have:

- 8 black balls
- 3 white balls
- 5 blue balls

how many ways there are to divide those balls into two different groups (note that there is no need to divide into two groups with even number of balls, one group could have 1 e the other 15).

In my first attempt I did this:
$${ 16!  \over (3!\cdot 5!\cdot 8!) } \cdot 17$$

The number of permutations times the number of ways to divide into two groups.  After some time I conclude this is wrong because it over calculate the permutations inside which group.

My second attempt I wrote this:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{16} {16 \choose i} $$

And again wrong, I figure out that I can't handle like having more than one ball per color. I hope this isn't too confusing and if anyone can help me it would be very helpful.

Comment: Note:  a group is determined by the number of black, white, and blue balls it contains.  You can do each color separately.  There are, for example, $9$ ways to divide the black balls.  How you interpret the final result will depend on whether or not the two groups were distinguished  other than by the balls they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just $ (8+1) \times (3+1) \times (5+1) =216$, by the product principle. The "plus 1's" come from the fact that you could have zero black balls on one side, (or zero White balls or zero blue balls).

Now, $216$ is the answer only if (a) you consider:

3 Black, 1 White and 4 Blue in "left group" and 5 Black, 2 White and 1 Blue in "right group"

*different to*: 5 Black, 2 White 1 Blue in "left group" and 3 Black, 1 White and 4 Blue in "right group"

*and*

you're OK with having one group being empty.

If you consider swapping groups as above to be *the same*, then just halve the 216.

And there are 2 out of 216 where 1 group is empty.

So you need to clarify your question a bit...